# merging PDFs in pyPDF on larger canvas

Tags: python, pypdf

What I am looking to do in pyPDF is create a script that will generate a 17x11 PDF "canvas", add the 1st PDF to the left side, and the 2nd PDF to the right side.

My initial question is: What is the method to generate an output PDF that does not share the dimensions of the original PDFs? IE: How do I generate a 17x11 PDF?

[image: My PDF guide]

Answer (score 2):

```
input1 = PdfFileReader(open('pdf1.pdf', 'rb'))
page1 = input1.getPage(0)

input2 = PdfFileReader(open('pdf2.pdf', 'rb'))
page2 = input2.getPage(0)

page3 = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, 17*72, 11*72)
#create a blankPage size is 17*11,1 inch equal 72 px

page3.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page1, 1, 0, 0)

#merge your pdf1 and pdf2 into the blank canvas
page3.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page2, 1, 8.5*72, 0)
```

Comment: You should add some explanation, instead of only posting code

Answer (score 1):

Use [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) with the [PageObject Class](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html).

It has a `page1.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(page2, rotation, tx, ty, expand=True)` command. With `expand=True` the `page1` will be extended.

See my answer to another question: [Python PyPDF2 join pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34646677/4187194)